# insertar imagen en SQL campo IMAGE con Java

Tags: java, sql, imagen

Quiero guardar mi imagen en una base de datos en SQL en un campo llamado fotoEmpleado de tipo `IMAGE`, hasta ahí todo bien, pues se me guarda en BYTES
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es a la hora de leerla, quiero mostrarla en un Label en mi formulario, tengo entendido que es obtener ese array de BYTES y convertirlo a imagen pero me manda un error `java.lang.NullPointerException` y no se como leerla. les dejo mis clases y métodos que utilizo (MVC):

Método que hace la consulta y recibe como parametro el idEmpleado:

```
public static String getImagenEmpleado(int idEmpleado) {

    String consulta = "SELECT fotoEmpleado FROM Empleado WHERE idEmpleado="+idEmpleado;
    return consulta;
}
```

Método que hace la conexión a la BD y ejecuta la consulta y convierte los BYTES a `IMAGE`:

```
public Image obtenerImagen(int idEmpleado) throws Exception {
    Image foto = null;
    //Creamos un objeto de conexion:
    ConexionSQL conexion = new ConexionSQL();
    //Declaramos el ResultSet:
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    //Establecemos la conexion con la BD:
    ConexionSQL.conectar();

    stmt = ConexionSQL.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(CommandsEmpleado.getImagenEmpleado(idEmpleado));

    //Iteramos sobre cada registro devuelto:
    if (rs.next()) {//si no encuentra la imagen
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fotoEmpleado");
        foto = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
    }

    //Cerramos el ResultSet:
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();

    //Cerramos la conexion:
    conexion.desconectar();

    //Devolvemos la foto del Empleado
    return foto;
}
```

y en la vista le mando el parámetro idEmpleado y le mando la imagen al label:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(controladorEmpleado.obtenerImagen(idEmpleado));

                if (image.getIconHeight() > 342 || image.getIconWidth() > 230) {
                    ImageIcon imageScalada = new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(90, 100, 100));
                    lblFotoEmpleado.setIcon(imageScalada);
                } else {
                    lblFotoEmpleado.setIcon(image);
                }
                ;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PanelEmpleados.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

¿o alguien sabe otra manera de guardar y mostrar la imagen en SQL y Java?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no estás nunca dando valor a la variable `foto`analizando este fragmento de código:

```
//Iteramos sobre cada registro devuelto:
if (!rs.next()) {//si no encuentra la imagen
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fotoEmpleado");
    foto = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
}
```

Se deduce que solo da valor a `foto` si el cursos hubiera alcanzado su último puntero sobre el ResultSet. Eso no nunca va a ocurrir siempre y cuando existan valores en el ResultSet. Así pues, deberías hacer los contrario:

```
// Se valida que existen valores.
if (rs.next()) { <-- // En caso de que existan valores
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fotoEmpleado");
    foto = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
}
```

Te dejo un enlace con la documentación de [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next());

Comment: Ya lo modifique y aún así me manda el `java.lang.NullPointerException` , y mis consultas están bien ya que en SQL la misma consulta si me devuelve el registro.

Comment: ¿Habrá otra manera para leer los Bytes y convertirlos a imagen y mostrarla  en un Label?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez deberias usar BufferedImage en vez de Image.

```
BufferedImage foto = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
```

Image como tal es una clase abstracta, mientras que BufferedImage extiende de ella y es la que he visto que es implementada para este tipo de situaciones.

**EDIT:** Estuve haciendo varias pruebas con partes de tu código y no me salio el error del null, te muestro la manera en la que lo hice para cargar la imagen de la base de datos.

```
 public Image obtenerImagen(int idEmpleado) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage foto = null;
    //Declaramos el ResultSet:
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    //Establecemos la conexion con la BD:
    stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT image FROM imagetest LIMIT 1;");
    //Iteramos sobre cada registro devuelto:
    if (rs.next()) {//si no encuentra la imagen
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");
        foto = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
    }
    //Cerramos el ResultSet:
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    //Devolvemos la foto del Empleado
    return foto;
}
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta, es basicamente tu mismo codigo, solo que le cambie el Image por BufferedImage y otros detalles para traer la información de mi base de datos (como mi propia conexion, el hecho de que no necesito el id del empleado, etc), pero del resto es lo mismo.

Con respecto a la parte de visualización, tu codigo sirvio basicamente igual, solo lo adapte para que me funcionara a mi.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageManager.obtenerImagen(1));
    JLabel lblFotoEmpleado = new JLabel();
    Frame frame = new Frame("Image Example");
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    lblFotoEmpleado.setSize(400,400);
    lblFotoEmpleado.setVisible(true);

    if (image.getIconHeight() > 342 || image.getIconWidth() > 230) {
        ImageIcon imageScalada = new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(90, 100, 100));
        lblFotoEmpleado.setIcon(imageScalada);
    } else {
        lblFotoEmpleado.setIcon(image);
    }

    frame.add(lblFotoEmpleado);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: Resultado al ejecutar mi codigo]

Lo único que se me ocurre que tengamos de diferente, es la manera en la que se guarda la imagen en la base de datos. Yo pues use un Longblob, el cual supongo que tu tambien y al guardalo en la base de datos me muestra lo siguiente, a comparación tuya que muestra los Bytes.

[image: Resultado en Base de datos]

Si algo, el codigo que utilice para guardar las imagenes fue el siguiente.

```
 public void saveImage(String ruta) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO imagetest(image) VALUES (?)";
    //Creamos una cadena para después prepararla
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    File image = new File(ruta);
    //ruta puede ser: "/home/cmop/Desktop/1.jpg"
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
    //Lo convertimos en un Stream
    stmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) image.length());
    //Asignamos el Stream al Statement
    stmt.execute();
}
```

Lamento no poder ayudarte más, la verdad aparte de lo que te comente, no se me ocurre otra causa de error.

Comment: ¿y para mostrarla en el label?, también ahí me pierdo, soy muy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Edite mi post principal con codigo ejemplo que yo utilice para poder realizar pruebas con tu codigo.

Comment: gracias @julidr más tarde lo reviso.